# How can I jump only to the exact function name with etags?

Tags: emacs, etag

I wanted to find the following function with etags:

```
dt()
```

but as I go through the tag table, I keep hitting functions with `dt` in their names,  like

```
widthThing1()
widthThing2()
...
```

making the definition of `dt()` extremely difficult to find.

Is there some way to search *only* for the exact function that I'm searching for with etags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up your TAGS file and see what it is actually indexing (which will vary by language, of course).

For instance, if the relevant entry looked like this:

```
function ds(^?6140,232332
```

Then you could use `function ds(` (or potentially just `ds(` ) as your search term, to ensure that you weren't matching other functions.

You could omit the "function" part of that, except that typing <kbd>SPC</kbd> at the `find-tag` prompt will invoke TAG completion. You could avoid that by typing <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> instead, or alternatively utilise `find-tag-regexp` bound to <kbd>C-M-.</kbd> which does not have the completion binding.

So <kbd>C-M-.</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> `ds(` <kbd>RET</kbd> might be convenient.

You may also want to look at the `etags-select` library and binding <kbd>M-.</kbd> to `etags-select-find-tag`, which I find provides a much better interface.

You can get that from the EmacsWiki, or Marmalade:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EtagsSelect
- http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/etags-select

Packages like Icicles and Helm also provide alternative interfaces. You can start reading at http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags